# Can't get ConfuserEx working and can't find alternative

Tags: c++-cli, obfuscation, confuserex

I have a C++/CLI program that I need to obfuscate. I use ConfuserEx for my C# program and it works fine, but when I use it with my C++/CLI program, then I run the program, I just get the spinning pointer and then it goes away. Nothing seems to open.

Thermida worked for it but I don't have the money to pay for that right now. Is there either a way to fix this problem or a cheap / free alternative that supports mixed-mode assemblies?

Thanks

Comment: I recently learned about "Eazfuscator.NET", but cannot attest to how well it works yet.

Comment: Strange that nobody ever replied. I also was interesting in an alternative to confuserex for *c* programs and I find it unbelievable that no such thing exists in the free/opensource realm and that nobody chimed in !